# Need help with error:: The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'objRadGrid' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Need help with binding error plz

> The type specified in the TypeName
>   property of ObjectDataSource
>   'objRadGrid' could not be found.

Why the above error ? I am cluless. The RadComboBox is binding alright, its finding the class in project2 and all. Why this error wen binding radgrid??

I have rebuild projects 2 a million times now and have checked the bllQuesType class over and over, have checked GetQuesType method so many times..

what's wrong ? :(

aspx page

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radgridQuesType" 
     EditMode="EditForms" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True"
     PageSize="15" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="objRadGrid"
     runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" 
     OnItemDataBound="radgridQuesType_OnItemDataBound"
     ShowStatusBar="True" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     OnItemCommand="radgridQuesType_OnItemCommand">
   <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Lang" 
     DataSourceID="objLang" TabIndex="2" Width="258px"
     SelectedValue='<%#Eval("LangID") %>'  runat="server" 
     DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="LangID">
</telerik:RadComboBox>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objRadGrid" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetQuesType" TypeName="Project2.bllQuesType">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objLang" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getLang" TypeName="Project2.bllLang">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the "project2.bllQuesType" class and the "GetQuesType" method?? Is "bllQuesType" really in the "Project2" namespace? Or maybe a sub-namespace of Project2 ??

Comment: Serenity, I was about to ask the same questions - kudos to marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bound the combobox in code behind. Then it all worked fine..weird